# Using react to fetch one item from json

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

So I got this problem.
I am trying to fetch a local json file from my project. The json file is stored in the src folder.

This is my json file

```
[
    {
      "name": "Sunsssset Beach",
      "email": "info@sunsetbeach.com",
      "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439130490301-25e322d88054?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80",
      "price": 85,
      "maxGuests": 18,
      "lat": 60.393388,
      "lng": 5.22872,
      "description": "Get ready for some amazing sunsets as you sip a cocktail and watch dolphins play in the harbour below.",
      "selfCatering": true,
      "createdAt": "2020-09-04T09:07:10.367Z",
      "id": "5f5203bedc17b0a4b302f211"
    },
    {
      "name": "The Hideaway",
      "email": "info@hideaway.com",
      "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551906993-c8b38a6ab201?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=666&q=80",
      "price": 70,
      "maxGuests": 2,
      "lat": 60.425168,
      "lng": 5.358141,
      "description": "This secluded wilderness cabin is the perfect spot for a restful and cosy getaway.",
      "selfCatering": true,
      "createdAt": "2020-09-04T09:07:10.370Z",
      "id": "5f5203bedc17b0a4b302f213"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rest Easy",
      "email": "management@resteasy.com",
      "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512552288940-3a300922a275?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80",
      "price": 120,
      "maxGuests": 14,
      "lat": 60.396779,
      "lng": 5.235602,
      "description": "Need some time off from your busy life to relax and unwind? Choose Rest Easy for the complete relaxation experience you desire.",
      "selfCatering": false,
      "createdAt": "2020-09-04T09:07:10.370Z",
      "id": "5f5203bedc17b0a4b302f212"
    }
  ]
```

And here is my project file

```
function Establishment() {
  const [establishment, setEstablishment] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("jsonfile")
      .then((response) => {
        // check if response returns ok
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          setErrorHandle(true);
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setEstablishment(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setErrorHandle(true);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Now I want to be able to press a button do display all of these items, and by clicking on one item, it should display only that item in a different page. How do I do that?

Let me know if there is anything else you need to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if the JSON data is in a local in your file system then **you do not need** **fetch or axios**

**Why you did not use Axios or Fetch?**

Axios or Fetch use to get or post data into the server. In our case, we read on the local folder file so that we use map().

**Note: most important when using Axios and Fetch we need URL parameter compulsory**

**Now what you are to do is:**

**1. Firstly Import the file wherever you want to use:**

`import data from "../static/data/myData.json";`

**2. Now you want to map through that Json file:**

```
<div>
    {
        data.map(myData, index)=>{
        
            return <div key={myData.id}>

                <h1>{myData.name}</h1>
                <h3>{myData.email}</h3>
            </div>


        }
    }  
</div>
```

- So that is how you want to handle this situation obviously structuring the content the way you desire not with **h1's and h3's** like I did